# AWS lambda cloudwatch subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to add a cloudwatch subscription to a AWS lambda logs thereby making my AWS lambda triggered by cloudwatch logs. What permissions should I add to the role which lambda is using to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lambda will by default have access to CloudWatch to write logs (with the default AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole), however if you want to manually add it this is the policy with the required permissions:

```
{
  "document": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
  "id": "xxxxx",
  "type": "managed",
  "arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}
```

Lambda function policy for CloudWatch event trigger on Lambda:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "uuid",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:invokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:LambdaFunction",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:us-east-x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:rule/CloudWatchRule"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Deiv , In my case I want cloudwatch events to trigger my lambda. Does the same policy apply for that?

Comment: That would be a different scenario, the wording in your question suggests access for Lambda logs -> cloudwatch :) however when you add a cloudwatch event trigger to your lambda, the policy will get added automatically (for lambda:invokefunction), so you shouldn't need to add anything

Comment: Agreed , my question is unclear :) I am trying to do it via terraform scripts , is there an example of this policy?

Comment: Updated my answer to include a policy for it :)